# Displaying Bangla (Unicode) fonts in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cordova, unicode

Is there any way to show Bangla (unicode) fonts in Windows phone 7? I have a project ongoing which should use a lot of Bangla text (an app for a local news media) and I've already completed the English version. If I can't do that normally, can the work done by using PhoneGap? Can anyone please lead me to the solution through some links, advice or tricks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same question many months ago, but then I have found this wonderful resource on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202920(v=vs.92).aspx .

In "Supported Reading Fonts in Windows Phone" section you will probably find all the needed information.